# how do you have 3 layers(layouts or objects) in an android app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been trying to figure out how have a background layout with 2 more layers on top.  When an imageView (person) is tapped, I want it to become a part of the boat, drawn on top of the boat.  This way, when the boat imageView is tapped, the person will move with the boat across the river.  I have the  boat moving back and forth when tapped, but want to set the person imageView to be like a child of the boat imageView when tapped on.  Right now I'm working on just getting the person to become a child of the boat imageView, but everything I have been trying just compiles, runs, and then displays everything in the right place except the person imageView is at the top left instead of inside the boat.  If someone could point out to me what I'm doing wrong and what the best way is to have multiple layers like this, I would appreciate it.

There are no errors, the person object just doesn't show up in the boat.

Here is the main activity:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup boatview = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.boatlayout,main,false);
    View personview = li.inflate(R.layout.personlayout,boatview,false);

    ((ViewGroup) main).addView(boatview);
    ((ViewGroup) boatview).addView(personview);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is the Boat class:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Boat extends ImageView {

boolean state = true;

public Boat(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

 public Boat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

 public Boat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

private void init()
{
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (state) {
                moveBoat(-215);
            } else {
                moveBoat(215);
            }
        }
    });
}

//TranslateAnimation animation;
//TranslateAnimation animation2;

public void moveBoat(int amount){
    /*
    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, amount);
    animation.setDuration(250);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    this.startAnimation(animation);
    */
    this.offsetTopAndBottom(amount);
    state = !state;
}
}
```

Here is the person class:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Person extends ImageView {

boolean state = true;

public Person(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

 public Person(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

 public Person(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

private void init()
{
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (state) {
                //movePerson(325,-230);
            } else {
                //movePerson(-325,230);
            }
        }
    });


}

public void movePerson(int x, int y)
{
    this.offsetLeftAndRight(x);
    this.offsetTopAndBottom(y);

    state = !state;
}

}
```

Here is the main layout for the background:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the boat layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/framelayoutView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
    android:id="@+id/boatimageView"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
    android:src="@drawable/boat" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And finally, here is the person layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.cannibal_photographer.Person
            android:id="@+id/personView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/greensquare"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```